# Logistic regression plot out of 1 and 0 limit?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, logistic-curve

[image]I'm plotting the interaction in logistic regression.

- Group is binary numeric variable = 1-0
- Levz is standardized numeric variable corresponding to scores of a questionnaires.
- quest is a 3 level character variable with level "low, average, high"

I am using this code:

```
plsmo(df$Levz, df$groupnum, datadensity = T, group = df$quest_3lvls, 
      col=c('black', 'red','green'), xlab = 'Lev', ylab ='Group', ylim= c(0,1))
```

However this is the results and it seems a bit odd to me as it looks as if it is outside the 1 and 0 boundaries.

I honestly am quite new to logistic regression, but this looks a bit odd to me. Am I right in doubting?

Comment: Hard to tell as we cannot see the figure and cannot reproduce anything without the data. Also not sure what your plotting but I guess it is the data  and not the fitted values. But again, hard to tell.

Comment: @horseoftheyear apologies, I was sure I had posted the picture. Now you should be able to see it.

Comment: @horseoftheyear and yes I am plotting the data not the fitted values.